# Can't encode object: function(){var d=Fa.apply(0,arguments).map(function(e){return c.cs(e)});d=t0a(c,a,d);return c.vj(d)}

Tags: google-earth-engine, clip

I'm having some trouble clipping images in google earth engine. The images have been clipped once before with a function laid out the exact same way but with different geography. I'm now getting strange error messages. The errors don't appear until I try to use the function.

[image]

Comment: Please, post code and errors as text, this makes it easier for people with the same question to find this post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is here:

```js
var IP_geo = NAIP_IP2006.geometry
```

`.geometry` is a method, a sort of function, but you did not call it. (That is why the error is about trying to encode a function.) The code should be:

```js
var IP_geo = NAIP_IP2006.geometry();
```

Any time you get an error like this, check for missing parentheses.